# Multiple table joins in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How do I write the mysql query below into rails activerecord

```
select
    A.*,
    B.* 
from
    raga_contest_applicants_songs AS A 
    join
        raga_contest_applicants AS B 
        ON B.contest_applicant_id = A.contest_applicant_id 
    join
        raga_contest_rounds AS C 
        ON C.contest_cat_id = B.contest_cat_id 
WHERE
    C.contest_cat_id = contest_cat_id 
GROUP BY
    C.contest_cat_id
```

I know how to write joins on two tables; however, I'm not very confident on how to use join on 3 tables.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

To rewrite the SQL query you've got in your question, I think it should be like the following (though I'm having a hard time fully visualizing your model relationships, so this is a bit of guesswork):

```
RagaContextApplicantsSong.
  joins(:raga_contest_applicants => [:raga_content_rounds], :contest_cat).
  group('raga_contest_rounds.contest_cat_id')
```

...such that the `joins` method takes care of both of the two joins as well as the `WHERE` clause, followed finally by the `group` call.

**As more for reference:**

If you're joining multiple associations to the same model [you can simply list them](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables):

```
Post.joins(:category, :comments)
Returns all posts that have a category and at least one comment
```

If you're joining nested tables you can list them as in a hash:

```
Post.joins(:comments => :guest)
Returns all comments made by a guest
```

Nested associations, multiple level:

```
Category.joins(:posts => [{:comments => :guest}, :tags])
Returns all posts with their comments where the post has at least one comment made by a guest
```

You can also chain ActiveRecord Query Interface calls such that:

```
Post.joins(:category, :comments)
...produces the same SQL as...
Post.joins(:category).joins(:comments)
```

If all else fails you can always [pass a SQL fragment directly into the `joins` method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#using-a-string-sql-fragment) as a stepping stone to getting from your working query to something more ARQI-centric

```
   Client.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN addresses ON addresses.client_id = clients.id')
=> SELECT clients.* FROM clients LEFT OUTER JOIN addresses ON addresses.client_id = clients.id
```

Comment: thanks a lot for effort you took to explain it in detail without having much info in question. I'm new to rails, after having worked in .net for 6 years I'm really having tough time to code rails way, but help from guys like you keeps me going.. thanks again..

Comment: My pleasure. Welcome to the Rails community. As Rubyists like to say [MINSWAN](http://blog.steveklabnik.com/posts/2011-08-19-matz-is-nice-so-we-are-nice)

Comment: Nested associations, multiple level #=> wizardry
Use simplified hash syntax `Category.joins(posts: [{comments: :guest}, :tags])`