# Rails 4 Active Record 2 different relations same model scope

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, squeel

I have these models:

```
SpaceShip < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :martian
  has_many :people

Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :skills

Martian < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :skill

Skill < ActiveRecord::Base

#rest omitted
```

I need to have a scope to find a spaceship where martian.skill.name = 'drive' or person.skill.name = 'drive'

It seems easy at first but it's not:

```
Spaceship < ActiveRecord::Base 
scope :by_skill_name, -> (skill_name){
                                     joins([[people: :skills], [martian: :skill]])
                                     .where('skills.name=?', skill_name)
                                     }
```

This scope won't work because only takes in count the association `martian.skill`.

I tried making the joins part in SQL and using table alias. It works but chaining with other scopes I get SQL errors.

I also tried with `joins(...).merge(joins(...))`but I'm still getting only the last relation.

Active Record doesn't have 'union' statement, I have seen some ways to implement it but I don't know if it's going to be too complicated and hacky.

Any idea?

Thanks.

EDIT:

By now I solved it using [squeel](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel) `where{(martian.skill.eq skill_name)|(people.skills.eq skill_name)}`but I'd like to know if it's possible in plain AR.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to set up a polymorphic relationship on `Skill` to even make this work? Can a `Person` and `Martian` ever share the same skill, or are you just dumping whatever in there?

Comment: Well, the real model is not exactly like this but here is no need to go polymorphic because the martian has a skill_id and people have the people_skills table. Perhaps the model is not very well implemented but it's how it was made, the martian skill is a new addition.

Comment: This looks quite similar... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16131201/multiple-table-joins-in-rails in terms of multi-joining

Comment: Thanks but it's not the same problem.

Comment: Gotcha. What SQL errors do you get?