# Rails Active Records Multiple joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is there any way I can get this SQL query by using ActiveRecord query syntax?

```
select t1.*
from
  t1
  join t2 on t1.id = t2.t1_id
  join t3 on t2.id = t3.t2_id
  join t4 on t3.id = t4.t3_id
  join t5 on t4.id = t5.t4_id
where t5.id = 5;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16131467/429758 should be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your query is that you're based off the database tables named **not** per Rails convention of having plural table names. I can provide an example similar to yours, it looks like this:

```
Universe.joins(
  galaxies: {
    stars: {
      planets: {
          molecules: :atoms
      }
    }
  }
).where(atoms: {id: 5})
```

And this query assumes you have models:

- `Universe` that `has_many :galaxies`
- `Galaxy` that `has_many :stars` and `belongs_to :universe` (as such, has `universe_id`)
- `Star` that `has_many :planets` and `belongs_to :galaxy`
- `Planet` that `has_many :molecules` and `belongs_to :star`
- `Molecule` that `has_many :atoms` and `belongs_to :planet`
- `Atom`... just `belongs_to :molecule`

Answer (score 0):

I would start by reading this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html and creating tables with names that somehow represent the data you are working with. Create migrations model classes with the proper associations and come back and update your question.