# Cant get this join to work in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, join

I'm trying to get the following join in rails

```
SELECT game_catergory_item.item_name, game_category_item_values.key, game_category_item_values.value
FROM game_category_item
INNER JOIN game_category_item_values
ON game_category.id = game_category_item.game_category_id;
WHERE game_category_item.game_gategory_id = 5
```

Here is my rails coding

```
def table
  game_id = 5
  @characters = GameCategory.joins(:game_category_items).
  select("game_catergory_items.name, game_category_item_values.key, game_category_item_values.value").
  where('game_category_item.game_gategory_id' => game_id)
end
```

and here is the output of the above coding

```
SELECT game_catergory_items.name, game_category_item_values.key, game_category_item_values.value 
FROM "game_categories" 
INNER JOIN "game_category_items" 
ON "game_category_items"."game_category_id" = "game_categories"."id" 
WHERE "game_category_item"."game_gategory_id" = 5
```

I've been going in circles for the past couple of hours. Its time I asked for help.

EDIT: One step closer after @davejal's help

```
GameCategoryItem.joins(:game_category_item_values).
select("game_category_items.name, game_category_item_values.key, game_category_item_values.value").
where('game_category_items.game_category_id' => game_id)
```

gives

```
SELECT game_category_items.name, game_category_item_values.key, game_category_item_values.value 
FROM "game_category_items" 
INNER JOIN "game_category_item_values" 
ON "game_category_item_values"."game_category_item_id" = "game_category_items"."id" 
WHERE "game_category_items"."game_category_id" = 5
```

The 'ON' tables and rows are now wrong.

Comment: The first query you have should not be able to execute in mysql, the `where` should be after the `join`

Comment: You will not get `game_category` table in the join on if you don't add the table in the query. Currently you're joining on two tables (`game_category_items` and `game_category_item_values`), where you also need `game_category`. So you need to add one more join to add that table.

Comment: add essential parts of you're db structure so I can be of more assistence

Comment: Here is a google doc with the db setup https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DBozqKO4OZ3NULKTQNwCDDX1tauc6bMUMEup7bCH7vY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: using the answer you gave returns `[#<GameCategoryItem id: nil, name: "bees">` which isn't what was requested to be selected, for some reason it doesn't select from the GameCategoryItemValue table as well

Comment: I think your query should be: `SELECT game_category_item.item_name, game_category_item_values.key, game_category_item_values.value
FROM game_category_item
INNER JOIN game_category_item_values
ON game_category_item.item_id= game_category_item_values.game_category_item_id
WHERE game_category_item.game_gategory_id = 5` see my updated answer and test it.

Comment: Thanks for helping. Your update still doesn't get the info from all the tables. it only gives me `<GameCategoryItem id: nil, name: "bees">` for each record instead of the `game_category_item.item_name, game_category_item_values.key, game_category_item_values.value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first query you have should not be able to execute in mysql, the where should be after the join like this:

```
SELECT game_catergory_item.item_name, game_category_item_values.key, game_category_item_values.value
FROM game_category_item
INNER JOIN game_category_item_values
ON game_category.id = game_category_item.game_category_id
WHERE game_category_item.game_gategory_id = 5;
```

Looking at your result I would change:

```
@characters = GameCategory.joins(:game_category_items).
```

into

```
@characters = GameCategoryItem.joins(:game_category_item_values).
```

**Update:**

According to your google docs document your query should be:

```
SELECT game_category_item.item_name, game_category_item_values.key, game_category_item_values.value FROM game_category_item INNER JOIN game_category_item_values ON game_category_item.item_id= game_category_item_values.game_category_item_id WHERE game_category_item.game_gategory_id = 5
```

Which results to your code to be:

```
def table
  game_id = 5
  @characters = GameCategoryItem.joins(:game_category_items_values).
  select("game_catergory_items.name, game_category_item_values.key, game_category_item_values.value").
  where('game_category_item.game_category_id' => game_id)
end
```

Also notice you had `game_gategory_id instead` of `game_category_id` in the where clause!

Comment: Thanks! I embarrassingly had spelling mistakes as well 'game_category_item.game_gategory_id' was supposed to be 'game_category_items.game_category_id'. I figured that out from the new error your replacement threw, the error my setup was giving didn't make sense your fix make the join right and pointed out the errors.

Comment: Hmm spoke too soon. It doesnt return what i need.   `GameCategoryItem Load (0.3ms)  SELECT game_category_items.name, game_category_item_values.key, game_category_item_values.value FROM "game_category_items" INNER JOIN "game_category_item_values" ON "game_category_item_values"."game_category_item_id" = "game_category_items"."id" WHERE "game_category_items"."game_category_id" = 9
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<GameCategoryItem id: nil, name: "griffins">` I need game_catergory_item.item_name, game_category_item_values.key and game_category_item_values.value

Comment: not sure what your problem is now, but according to what you want your query to be it's the correct output. It would be helpful to add your db schema, then maybe I can see some other problem.

Comment: if for some reason you still need one more table in the join refer to [this question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16131201/3664960)

Comment: running the sql you gave works! But If i run the Rails join command it converts it to the right sql but doesn't output the correct tables like just running the sql does, its strange (running them in rails console).

Comment: Ok it doesnt work in the console for some random rails reason that im not aweara of but works fine on the table. THANKS A BUNCH