# Rails & Active Record: how to join tables that are only related through another table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to build an active record query using through table associations. Here are my models:

Event.rb:

```
has_many :event_keywords
```

User.rb:

```
has_many :user_keywords
```

Keyword.rb:

```
has_many :event_keywords
has_many :user_keywords
```

EventKeyword.rb:

```
belongs_to :event
belongs_to :keyword
```

UserKeyword.rb:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :keyword
```

I am trying to build an Event scope that takes a user_id as a param and returns all the Events with shared keywords. This was my attempt but it's not recognizing the user_keywords association:

```
 scope :with_keywords_in_common, ->(user_id) {
     joins(:event_keywords).joins(:user_keywords)
     .where("user_keywords.user_id = ?", user_id)
     .where("event_keywords.keyword_id = user_keywords.keyword_id")
  }
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work. 2-step process. First, get all user's keywords. Then find all events with the same keyword.

```
scope :with_keywords_in_common, ->(user) {
  joins(:event_keywords).
    where("event_keywords.keyword_id" => user.user_keywords.pluck(:id))
}
```

Comment: Awesome, this looks perfect! All I had to change was user.user_keywords.pluck(:id) to user.user_keywords.pluck(:keyword_id)

Answer (score 0):

The database seems to be overkill here and firstly I'd simplify by making keywords polymorphic, this would get rid of 2 of your tables here (`event_keywords`, and `user_keywords`).

Your associations would then look like this:

```
# Event.rb:
has_many :keywords, as: keywordable

# User.rb:
has_many :keywords, as: keywordable

# Keyword.rb:
belongs_to :keywordable, polymorphic: true
```

And finally, your scope:

```
scope :with_keywords_in_common, -> (user_id) do
  joins(:keywords)
  .where('keywords.keywordable_type = User AND keywords.word IN (?)', keywords.pluck(:name))
end
```

Comment: There's other reasons for having the extra tables that I didn't include in the question to keep it simple. Do you know how you'd build this scope if I keep the DB setup the same?

Comment: Here's an attempt but the reason why your `user_assocations` table isnt found is because it is a nested table. Although Sergio's answer will work, it might be optimized further through a nested join. Here is a link to get you started, but without your tables and data, I cant test anything. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16131201/multiple-table-joins-in-rails